# text detection by finding maximal stable extreme regions of an image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am doing text detection from an image which have perspective `view. vl_feat` is good for this.

but i got some error:

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_mser as a function:
>       H:\maincode\vl_mser.m
>       Error in ==> TextDetection at 47
>       `[r,f] = vl_mser(Gray_image,'MinDiversity',0.7,'MaxVariation',0.2,'Delta',10);`

Any one can you help me to avoid this error and run the code

thanks for your help sir .I avoided multiple identically-named .m files and run the program L got the error like this and i changed it After that i run the program.I got the output but while taking the MSER error occurred and given below 
Automatic Text Detection: Starting DEMO...
Automatic Text Detection: Ready.

Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
H:\mainproject\codes\RET_2014-master\Files\vlfeat\toolbox\mex\mexw32.

> In path at 110
>     In addpath at 87
>     In vl_setup at 78
>     In run at 57
>     In TextDetectionDemo>pushbutton1_Callback at 128
>     In gui_mainfcn at 96
>     In TextDetectionDemo at 42
>     In @(hObject,eventdata)TextDetectionDemo('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>   ??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_mser as a function:
>   H:\mainproject\codes\RET_2014-master\Files\vlfeat\toolbox\mser\vl_mser.m

Error in ==> TextDetectionDemo>pushbutton1_Callback at 134
[r,f] =
vl_mser(Gray_image,'MinDiversity',MinDiversity,'MaxVariation',MaxVariation,'Delta',Delta)
;

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> TextDetectionDemo at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)TextDetectionDemo('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Anyone can help me to clear this pls..

Comment: Try this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you have either made changes to `vl_mser.m` (e.g. added code above the function definition), or that you have two files named `vl_mser.m` and MATLAB is picking the wrong one (sometimes called "shadowing").

The code expects a function (something you can call with inputs and get outputs), and it's finding a script (something that just runs a set of statements and takes no input). If you don't understand the difference, you should read through the [Mathworks help](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html).

First, try this:

```
which vl_mser.m
```

This should show you where MATLAB is finding `vl_mser.m`, the function it's trying to run.

Then this:

```
which vl_mser.m -all
```

This will show you all the files called vl_mser.m on the path.

The simplest way to resolve this is to make sure that you do not have multiple identically-named .m files.

Comment: thanks for your help sir .I avoided multiple identically-named .m files and run the program L got the error like this and i changed it After that i run the program.I got the output but while taking the MSER error occurred and given below